# ESS - how to disable sublimity mode for R console only?

Tags: ess, r

Is there a way to keep sublimity mode for R source buffers, while disabling it for the R console?

Answer (score 1):

ESS puts the R console buffer into `iESS`, or `inferior-ess-mode`, and the source buffers are in `ESS[S]` or `r-mode`.

`R-mode-hook` runs when you open a new source buffer, so anything you put in that will only effect your source buffers.`inferior-ess-mode-hook` runs when you start an R console, so anything in there should only apply to the console buffer and not the source.

Comment: Thanks. The sublimity-mode variable value affects use of sublimity-mode globally. Do you know if there's a way to turn sublimity mode on or off for a particular  buffer?

Comment: I don't know anything about sublimity-mode. From the Emacs wiki page, it looks like it can be used on a per-buffer or global way. So you could turn it on in your r-mode hook, and leave it off your inferior-ess-mode hook. Then you would also have to add it to the mode hooks for any other modes you want to enable it for.